# I want to create Dynamic Products Ads for facebook but, there is no " Product catalog sales " objective while creating a Campaign

Tags: facebook

I want to build **dynamic product ads** for facebook, in my Business Manager Account I added **Ad Account** having **Indian Currency and Timezone**. I have created **product catlog** and also setup the **product feed**. I tried to Create **Campaign** in power editor for dynamic ads having **objective** **"product sales catlog"** but, there is no such objective.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here - 
1. Objectives a campaign has is a fixed set -

> CANVAS_APP_ENGAGEMENT, CANVAS_APP_INSTALLS, EVENT_RESPONSES, LOCAL_AWARENESS, MOBILE_APP_ENGAGEMENT, MOBILE_APP_INSTALLS , OFFER_CLAIMS, PAGE_LIKES, POST_ENGAGEMENT, VIDEO_VIEWS, WEBSITE_CLICKS, WEBSITE_CONVERSIONS

More info - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcampaign/v2.3

2. The steps you've taken so far to create dynamic product ads are on track but there are more steps before they can be used.

> The steps for creating a Dynamic ad are:
>   1.Create a Product Catalog
>   2.Create and Schedule a Product Feed
>   3.Create a Product Set
>   4.Set up your Custom Audience Pixel to track events Dynamic Product Ads
>   5.Create a Product Audience
>   6.Create a Dynamic Ad Template
>   7.Create a Dynamic Ad Group
>
> 8. Fetch per product ad statistics
>
> More info on the steps - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/v2.3

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to create a Dynamic Product Ad Campaign and this is what it says on the support page - "Dynamic product ads use the PRODUCT_CATALOG_SALES objective."(link:https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2015/02/17/introducing-dynamic-product-ads/). Now the problem is that I don't see that objective in the list of options. So, how do I proceed? Is it possible to use some other objective for creating Dynamic Product Ad Campaign?